# unable to select rows in table widget In PyQGIS

Tags: python, pyqt, qgis, pythonqt

In PyQGIS design tablewidget, I have set table widget to be read-only and when I select particular,it is didn't read that row?

```
self.dlg.ui.tableWidget.item(row, 1).setFlags(Qt.NoItemFlags)
```

unable to select rows in table widget,to read datas.

Comment: you could explain yourself better, place an appropriate title, and take advantage of giving more details, you have a lot of space, please read [ask], it is difficult to understand what you want.

Comment: Nothing i will just simply tell you,i set the tablewidget in pyqt as readonly and i cannot able to select any row,so please tell me there is any option to read the rows in readonly mode itself.

Comment: From what I understand, you do not want the cells to be editable, but they can be selected. I am right?

Comment: yes right,can you suggest me any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to use bitwise operations to deny the flag `Qt.ItemIsEditable`

```
it = self.dlg.ui.tableWidget.item(row, 1)
it.setFlags(it.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsEditable)
```